# Compile error on Real World Haskell example

Tags: haskell

I am writing up a piece of code from "Real World Haskell" :

```
 ghc --make ch04/InteractWith.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ch04/InteractWith.hs, ch04/InteractWith.o )

ch04/InteractWith.hs:9:5: parse error on input `args'
```

dan@dbmint ~/testHaskell $ cat ch04/InteractWith.hs

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)

interactWith function inputFile outputFile = do
  input <- readFile inputFile
  writeFile outputFile (function input)

main = mainWith myFunction
  where mainWith function = do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of 
      [input, output] -> interactWith function input output
      _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"

myFunction = id
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrong indentation. The do-block (the `args <- getArgs ...` part) is at the same level as the start of the `mainWith` definition.

This compiles without errors:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)

interactWith function inputFile outputFile = do
  input <- readFile inputFile
  writeFile outputFile (function input)

main = mainWith myFunction
  where
    mainWith function = do
      args <- getArgs
      case args of
        [input, output] -> interactWith function input output
        _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"

myFunction = id
```

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation  Haskell's indentation rules are precise and not always friendly to new users.

Answer (score 2):

The whitespace is off

```hs
import System.Environment (getArgs)

interactWith function inputFile outputFile = do
    input <- readFile inputFile
    writeFile outputFile (function input)

main = mainWith myFunction
    where
        mainWith function = do
            args <- getArgs
            case args of 
                [input, output] -> interactWith function input output
                _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"

myFunction = id
```